# Playing video file with 1.5x, 2x speed

Tags: iphone, ios, video, mpmovieplayercontroller

I am an iOS developer who should make an app to play video with various speed.
I think there is no API to change playback speed on `MPMoviePlayerController`.

And I couldn't find any solutions.

Can you please tell me how to implement it?
or Can you please tell me any Framework/library(SDK) that support above functions for iOS?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There actually is such property.

`MPMoviePlayerController` adheres to the [MPMediaPlayback protocol](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/mediaplayer/reference/MPMediaPlayback_protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/MPMediaPlayback)

See

```
currentPlaybackRate
```

> The current playback rate for the player. (required)

```
@property(nonatomic) float currentPlaybackRate
```

> Discussion
>
> This value represents a multiplier for the default playback rate of
>   the current item. A value of 0.0 indicates that playback is stopped
>   while a value of 1.0 indicates that playback is occurring at normal
>   speed. Positive values indicate forward playback while negative values
>   indicate reverse playback.
>
> Setting the value of this property changes the playback rate
>   accordingly.

Comment: Thank you for your help! It's very easy. :)