# I want to play video in iPhone, at 2x speed

Tags: iphone, ios, uiview, mpmovieplayercontroller

I used MPMoviePlayerController, to play video. But there are no method/property to play video in 2x speed.

Is there any other way to play video at 2x speed?

I used this method to play Video.

```
-(void)playMovie:(NSString *)fileName

{

NSLog(@" File name :: %@",fileName);

NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];

NSString *moviePath = [bundle pathForResource:fileName ofType:@"mp4"];

NSLog(@"\n\n  moviePath :: %@",moviePath);

NSURL *url = [[NSURL fileURLWithPath:moviePath] retain];

moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:url];

moviePlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleDefault;

moviePlayer.shouldAutoplay = YES;

moviePlayer.view.frame = [[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame];

[moviePlayer.view setFrame:playVideoView.bounds];

[playVideoView addSubview:moviePlayer.view];

[moviePlayer setFullscreen:YES animated:YES];

}
```

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9050631/playing-video-file-with-1-5x-2x-speed

Comment: Possible duplicate question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10514185/play-forward-video-in-2x-3x-4x-speed-iphone-sdk

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`MPMoviePlayerController` conforms to the `MPMediaPlayback` [protocol](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/mediaplayer/reference/MPMediaPlayback_protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/MPMediaPlayback), which has the following property:

```
@property(nonatomic) float currentPlaybackRate
```

Comment: Can I play the online scream via this controller? I want to play online mp4 at 2x speed.